# how to convert generated 2 digit random number to alphabets

Tags: java

```
package com.nusecond.Code;
import java.util.*;
public class Code1 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
         HashMap<Integer, Character> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();
         hmap.put(0, 'D');
         hmap.put(1, 'G');
         hmap.put(2, 'B');
         hmap.put(3, 'Q');
         hmap.put(4, 'P');
         hmap.put(5, 'M');
         hmap.put(6, 'R');
         hmap.put(7, 'Y');
         hmap.put(8, 'Z');
         hmap.put(9, 'I');

Iterator<Integer> keySetIterator = hmap.keySet().iterator();
while(keySetIterator.hasNext()){
int key=keySetIterator.next();


System.out.println("key:" + key +  " value: "  +hmap.get(key));

}   
for(int j=1001;j<9999;j++);
Random random=new Random();
int res=random.nextInt(100);
System.out.println(res);
    }
    }
```

output:

```
key:0 value: D
key:1 value: G
key:2 value: B
key:3 value: Q
key:4 value: P
key:5 value: M
key:6 value: R
key:7 value: Y
key:8 value: Z
key:9 value: I
12
```

---

Here i'm trying to convert generates 2 digit random number to alphabets 
for example in the above in place of 12 i want GB.......
like that....
any help.....thanks in advance....
i have a deadline to finish this....
so plzz help me.......

Comment: Forget that you are generating a random number between 0 and 99 for a minute, and pretend it is between 0 and 9 - do you know how you would get the single letter for that number?

Comment: user defined characters storing in integers between 0 to 9 using hashmap

Comment: if i use the random generator method it'll generate any 2 digit number between 10 to 99 (ex if output is 23 i want that 23 in alphabet format like you see in the map 2 means B and 3 means Q so final reselt must be BQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below code,

```
HashMap<Integer, Character> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();
hmap.put(0, 'D');
hmap.put(1, 'G');
hmap.put(2, 'B');
hmap.put(3, 'Q');
hmap.put(4, 'P');
hmap.put(5, 'M');
hmap.put(6, 'R');
hmap.put(7, 'Y');
hmap.put(8, 'Z');
hmap.put(9, 'I');

Iterator<Integer> keySetIterator = hmap.keySet().iterator();
while(keySetIterator.hasNext()){
int key=keySetIterator.next();


System.out.println("key:" + key +  " value: "  +hmap.get(key));

}
for(int j=1001;j<9999;j++);
Random random=new Random();
int res=random.nextInt(100);
System.out.println(res);
String s = "";
s = String.valueOf(res);
String result="";

for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{
    result+=hmap.get(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i))));
}

System.out.println(result);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, I understood your idea clear. But try this:

```
String s = "";
s = String.valueOf(res);
System.out.println(hmap.get(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(s.charAt(0)))) + "" + hmap.get(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(s.charAt(1)))));
```

If `res` is 12, the result `GB` etc.
Declare `s` before and put the second and third row of my code inside your `for`

Comment: But notice it doesn't work for **0<=res<10** But I don't know what are you going to do with one digit numbers.

Comment: Converting an int to a string to extract a character to convert it back to an int... If only there were a better way. Also: doesn't work if `res < 10`. Also: no need to assign `""` to `s`.

Comment: Yep. Agree totally. That was my first idea but not the best.

Answer (score 0):

you can use i % 10 for getting ones and  i / 10 for getting decimal, for example:

```
int i = 12;
System.out.println(i / 10); // would be 1
System.out.println(i % 10); // would be 2
```

then use it to feed your hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Random random = new Random();
    IntStream.generate(() -> random.nextInt(100))
        .limit(1000)
        .mapToObj(i -> "" + hmap.get(i / 10) + hmap.get(i % 10))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this program as it gives the output as mentioned. Hope this helps.**

```
    int [] digit_face;  
        int digits=0;          
         HashMap<Integer, Character> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();
         hmap.put(0, 'D');
         hmap.put(1, 'G');
         hmap.put(2, 'B');
         hmap.put(3, 'Q');
         hmap.put(4, 'P');
         hmap.put(5, 'M');
         hmap.put(6, 'R');
         hmap.put(7, 'Y');
         hmap.put(8, 'Z');
         hmap.put(9, 'I');


for(int j=1001;j<9999;j++);
Random random=new Random();
int res=random.nextInt(100);

for(int i=res;i>0;i=(i/10)){
    digits++;
}

digit_face=new int[digits];

digits=0;

for(int i=res;i>0;i=(i/10)){
    digit_face[digits]=i%10;
    digits++;
}

for(int i=(digits-1);i>=0;i--){
    System.out.print(hmap.get(digit_face[i]));
}
```

Comment: key:0 value: D
key:1 value: G
key:2 value: B
key:3 value: Q
key:4 value: P
key:5 value: M
key:6 value: R
key:7 value: Y
key:8 value: Z
key:9 value: I
32
The Key values are:-

Comment: i don't want all that stuff in my console i need only two alphabets like if the generated random number is 34 i want QP only in my console